# How do I prevent text styled with user-select: none from being copied?

Tags: javascript, css

I've built an inventory management application which is being used in a retail environment. It displays buy/sale information as follows:

```
    Product Name
    Employee Name
    SKU
    Date
```

At the end of the day, an employee will copy/paste any buys/sales into a form. The only information that is desirable is the product name, so I applied `user-select: none` to the other information. This does prevent the text from being selected, but it creates another issue. The pasted text appears with white space in place of the non-selectable text. It looks like this when pasted:

```
    Product 1



    Product 2



    Product 3
```

I would like it to look like this when pasted:

```
    Product 1
    Product 2
    Product 3
```

Is there a way to prevent the lines styled with `user-select: none` from being copied at all? Or at least get rid of the white space when the clipboard is pasted?

Comment: if you have control over the target form you could use JS to trim the whitespace, use the oninput event.

Comment: It should work. I cannot reproduce your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/5kwp70nm/ That's why you should really provide your HTML code, so we can see what is going wrong.

Comment: it also works fine for me (in that fiddle) but it could be browser specific

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by replacing multi-line white space to one single new line character.

```js
let str = `    Product 1



    Product 2



    Product 3`.replace(/\n+/g, '\n'); // \n = new line

console.log(str);
```

Or you can make a button to copy the text of an element, and copy only the values of elements, that need to be copied. This can be done with `document.execCommand('copy');` after placing the value into the textarea, and selecting it.